# Affine Code Errors

Tags: c, encryption

So I've been trying to experiement with some decryption algorithms and ciphers and tried to do some of them on my own. At them moment I'm writing in C an affine algorithm which I am trying to decrypt a line from a .txt file which I decrypted myself so here's where I think my problem appears since my code always pops text file corrupted and doesn't proceed to the next task.

```
 file = fopen("encr_affine.txt", "r");
if(file)
{
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
}


fgets(str,100,file);

if ( fgets(str,100,file) == NULL )                      
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Text file corrupted\n");           
   return -1;
}
```

What is the mistake here? Is it reading the whole line of the txt file or just the first char? And why it doesn't proceed on into the next tasks?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can `rewind` the file (if you don't `fclose` it).

Comment: Did you just edit your question to something completely different after getting an answer to what you asked before?

Comment: Please don't drastically change your question once it got attention. By doing that you invalidate most if not all existing comments and answers. If you got a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

It always prints your `Text file corrupted` message because the file is always closed (or never open) when it gets there.

Look what this first part does:

```
file = fopen("encr_affine.txt", "r");
if(file)
{
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
}
```

It opens the file, then (if it's really open), it reads the *entire* file, byte by byte, then prints it all to stdout.  It then *closes* the file.

Then you try to do stuff on a *closed* file:

```
fgets(str,100,file);
```

This would do nothing because the file is closed, and would return `NULL`.  If the file were never opened, it would still return `NULL` due to an error.

But then you try it again:

```
if ( fgets(str,100,file) == NULL )                      
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Text file corrupted\n");           
   return -1;
}
```

This `fgets(str,100,file)` *always* returns `NULL` because once again the file is closed.

Perhaps what you really want to do is to process the bytes one at a time in your first loop before printing them with `putchar()`.